# A strange error from an algorithm

Tags: r, statistics

I have written this function that computes the MLE from a Cauchy distribution numerically based on the Newton-Raphson algorithm:

```
mlec <- function(x,theta0=median(x),numstp=100,eps=0.01){
    numfin <- numstp
    ic <- 0
    istop <- 0
    while(istop==0){
        ic <- ic+1
        ltheta <- -2*sum((x-theta0)/(1+(x-theta0)^2))
        lprimetheta <- -2*(sum(2*(x-theta0)^2/
                            (1+(x-theta0)^2)^2-1/(1+(x-theta0)^2)^2))
        theta1 <- theta0-(ltheta/lprimetheta)
        check <- abs((theta1-theta0)/theta1)
        if(check < eps ) { istop <- 1 }
        theta0 <- theta1
    }
    list(theta1=theta1,check=check,realnumstps=ic)
}
```

The goal is then to generate observations from a Cauchy distribution with scale parameter 2 and see how the MLE performs. The problem is that while for some samples, the MLE runs wonderfully for others I get the strange error

```
Error in if (check < eps) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What is going on here? I have defined what "check" is so that shouldn't happen.

Thank you.

Comment: @RichardScriven Nop, that is not it.

Comment: What values make it run without error, and what values trigger the error?

Comment: @RichardScriven Well I generate a new sample by rcauchy(100,2) each time, so it's hard to tell precisely which values are allowed.

Comment: so find a reproducible example for us (with `set.seed()`) ...

Comment: Here's what you do: put in a line that either writes the value of `check` to a global variable every time prior to your `if` statement, or put in a `if(is.na(check) |is.null(check)) stop(paste('bad check value of ', check))`

Comment: @BenBolker set.seed(4) x<-rcauchy(100,2). The function runs perfectly here.

Comment: We need you to give us an example that *doesn't* work ...

Comment: `for (i in 1:1000) { cat(i,"\n"); set.seed(i); x <- rcauchy(100,2); mlec(x) }` shows that it fails if we `set.seed(1)` ...

Comment: @BenBolker set.seed(6) x<-rcauchy(100,2). This does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've added a little bit of instrumentation (see the `cat()` statement in the middle), and fixed the second-derivative expression (`fixed`: see below):

```
mlec <- function(x,theta0=median(x),numstp=100,eps=0.01,
                 debug=TRUE,fixed=FALSE){
    numfin <- numstp
    ic <- 0
    istop <- 0
    while(istop==0){
        ic <- ic+1
        ltheta <- -2*sum((x-theta0)/(1+(x-theta0)^2))
        lprimetheta <- -2*(sum(2*(x-theta0)^2/
                            (1+(x-theta0)^2)^2-1/(1+(x-theta0)^2)^2))
        if (!fixed) {
            theta1 <- theta0-(ltheta/lprimetheta)
        } else theta1 <- theta0-ltheta/ff(theta0)
        check <- abs((theta1-theta0)/theta1)
        if (debug) cat(ic,ltheta,lprimetheta,theta0,theta1,check,"\n")
        if(check < eps ) { istop <- 1 }
        theta0 <- theta1
    }
    list(theta1=theta1,check=check,realnumstps=ic)
}

set.seed(1)
x <- rcauchy(100,2)

mlec(x)
```

Here's the tail end of the output:

```
## ic  ltheta        lprimetheta      theta0        theta1     check
## 427 -4.48838e-75 -2.014555e-151 -4.455951e+76 -6.683926e+76 0.3333333 
## 428 -2.992253e-75 -8.953579e-152 -6.683926e+76 -1.002589e+77 0.3333333 
## 429 -1.994835e-75 -3.979368e-152 -1.002589e+77 -1.503883e+77 0.3333333 
## 430 -1.32989e-75 0 -1.503883e+77 -Inf NaN
```

Now, why is it happening?  Either you've got a bug somewhere, or the algorithm is unstable.  **tl;dr** it turns out the answer is actually "both"; your second-derivative expression seems wrong, but even it were correct the N-R algorithm is *extremely* unstable for this problem.

Here are your derivative and second-derivative functions (I'm wrapping them with `Vectorize()` for convenience so I can evaluate these at multiple `theta` values simultaneously):

```
lthetafun <- Vectorize(function(theta) {
    -2*sum((x-theta)/(1+(x-theta)^2))
})
lprimethetafun <- Vectorize(function(theta) {
    -2*(sum(2*(x-theta)^2/
                (1+(x-theta)^2)^2-1/(1+(x-theta)^2)^2))
})
```

A negative log-likelihood function based on the built-in `dcauchy` function:

```
thetafun <- Vectorize(function(theta) -sum(dcauchy(x,theta,log=TRUE)))
```

Check differentiation (at an arbitrarily chosen point):

```
library("numDeriv")
all.equal(grad(thetafun,2),lthetafun(2))  ## TRUE
```

Check second derivative:

```
hessian(thetafun,2) ## 36.13297
lprimethetafun(2)   ## 8.609859: ???
```

I think your second-derivative expression is wrong.

The following alternative second-derivative function is based on lazily cheating with Wolfram Alpha, differentiating your gradient function (which matches with the finite-difference approximation):

```
ff <- Vectorize(function(theta)
    2*sum(((x-theta)^2-1)/((x-theta)^2+1)^2))
ff(2)  ## matches hessian() above.
```

But it looks like you may have further problems.

The negative log-likelihood surface looks OK:

```
curve(thetafun, from=-10,to=10,n=501)
```

[image]

But trouble is on the horizon:

```
curve(lthetafun, from=-10,to=10, n=501)
```

[image]

This looks irregular, and going up one level to the second derivative shows that it is:

```
curve(ff, from=-10, to=10, n=501)
```

[image]

Here's the curve of N-R updates:

```
ff2 <- function(x) x-lthetafun(x)/ff(x)
curve(ff2, from=-10, to=10, n=501,ylim=c(-100,100))
```

[image]

Yikes!  This indicates why the Newton-Raphson method could go wrong unless you start close enough to the minimum (any time the likelihood surface has an inflection point, the N-R updating curve will have a pole ...). Further analysis of the problem would probably tell you why the second derivative of the Cauchy is so scary.

If you just want to find the MLE you can do it by some more robust 1-D method:

```
library("bbmle")
mle2(x~dcauchy(location=m),
     data=data.frame(x),
     start=list(m=median(x)),
     method="Brent",
     lower=-100,upper=100)
## 
## Call:
## mle2(minuslogl = x ~ dcauchy(location = m), start = list(m = median(x)), 
##     method = "Brent", data = data.frame(x), lower = -100, upper = 100)
## 
## Coefficients:
##       m 
## 1.90179 
## 
## Log-likelihood: -262.96 
##
```

If you start close enough, N-R seems to work OK:

```
  mlec(x,1.85,debug=FALSE,fixed=TRUE,eps=0.0001)
 ## $theta1
 ## [1] 1.901592
 ## 
 ## $check
 ## [1] 5.214763e-05
 ## 
 ## $realnumstps
 ## [1] 37079
```

Comment: Thank you. Why does this keep happening though?

Comment: Yes that is right. lprimetheta is the second derivative of the log likelihood wr.t to the location parameter theta. We need that to set up the Newton Raphson.

Comment: Brilliant,thank you very much for sharing all that! I think the morale of the story is pick your starting point carefully. I picked the sample median because I knew it is a consistent estimator of the population median, i.e. theta. Of course the distribution has great variability and the algorithm does not always converge. So there is always this caveat. I am sure I could use another function like optimize instead but the NR is so instructive most of the time. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, I would say the moral is to pick a more robust optimizer.  Newton-Raphson is very intuitive, and very efficient if (1) the derivatives are all available and (2) the problem is well-behaved, but it's usually easy to do better, even in more than one dimension.